# Merge seperate dataframes and copy to Excel

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, join, merge

would like to join/merge two different dataframes.

Here is dataframe 1:

```
fruits = [('01.12.2020', 'Apples', 1.5), 
          ('02.12.2020', 'Apples', 1.0), 
          ('03.12.2020', 'Apples', 2.0),
          ('01.12.2020', 'Strawberry', 2.0), 
          ('02.12.2020', 'Strawberry', 2.5),
          ('02.12.2020', 'Strawberry', 2.0),
          ('01.12.2020', 'Lemon', 1.0), 
          ('02.12.2020', 'Lemon', 2.5),
          ('03.12.2020', 'Lemon', 2.5)]

fruitsDf = pd.DataFrame(fruits, columns=['Date', 'Fruit', 'Price'])
```

Dataframe 2:

```
pricelist = [('01.12.2020', 1.0, 2.5, 1.0), 
             ('02.12.2020', 1.5, 2.0, 3.5), 
             ('03.12.2020', 2.0, 2.0, 3.0 )]

pricelistDf = pd.DataFrame(pricelist, columns=['Date', 'Apple', 'Strawberry', 'Lemon'])
```

In the end I want to compare both price from "fruitsDf" and "pricelistDf" in "fruitsDf" ideal by using a loop as the actual dataframes have way more prices to compare and a lot of different fruits ;-)...

So the result should look like this where the "Close Price" column is representing the prices from "pricelistDF":

```
fruits = [('01.12.2020', 'Apples', 1.5, 1.0), 
            ('02.12.2020', 'Apples', 1.0, 1.5), 
            ('03.12.2020', 'Apples', 2.0, 2.0),
            ('01.12.2020', 'Strawberry', 2.0, 2.5), 
            ('02.12.2020', 'Strawberry', 2.5, 2.0),
            ('02.12.2020', 'Strawberry', 2.0, 2.0),
            ('01.12.2020', 'Lemon', 1.0, 1.0), 
            ('02.12.2020', 'Lemon', 2.5, 3.5),
            ('03.12.2020', 'Lemon', 2.5, 3.0)]

fruitsDf = pd.DataFrame(fruits, columns=['Date', 'Fruit', 'Price', 'Close Price'])
```

Furthermore I want to split the dataframe "fruitsDf" in "appleDf", "strawberryDf" and "lemonDf" in order to save each newly created dataframe in a separate tab of an Excel sheet.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with SQL JOINs you might find the merge method useful.

```
df1.merge(df2, ...)
```

I think you need to use how="outer"

```
Help on function merge in module pandas.core.reshape.merge:

merge(left, right, how: str = 'inner', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index: bool = False, right_index: bool = False, sort: bool = False, suffixes=('_x', '_y'), copy: bool = True, indicator: bool = False, validate=None) -> 'DataFrame'
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html